# Passing font file (ttf) to be use in popup tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A part of my code converts the page when they click the print button. It has a template but because I spawn another tab, all the style and css are not pass through. My biggest problem is the font, our font we use TTF files, I try loading the TTF files on the popup but it's not working properly (maybe because it's outside the file system). Any workaround for it?

Comment: https://www.jotform.com/blog/css-perfect-print-stylesheet-98272/

Comment: Thanks Matt, it doesn't say how you import TTF files or am I missing something

Comment: TTF fonts only work if they're on the system loading the page. You may have to convert to WOFF2 if you need to include it on clients you don't have control over.

Comment: Interesting, so how would the process go? I convert the TTF font into WOFF2 file then how would I pass that on my client

Comment: Yep you host the font just like an image (or use a CDN) and each client downloads it.

Comment: I see, interesting. will do some reading on this, weird it doesn't work the same way as TTF

Comment: Tested using WOFF2, it's resulting to unable to load content. Same thing on my TTF font

Comment: If you create a print stylesheet does it make a difference?